# Can $translate.instant be used with only the translationId and forceLanguage?

Tags: angular-translate

I need to use $translate.instant but I don't need any interpolation or a sanitize strategy. Problem is, when I use blank strings, objects, or undefined in place of those parameters, the translation results in the fallback instead of the selected language.

What am I missing?

Comment: If i get you correctly yes we can use $translate.instant with forceLanguage. https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate  . I believe you can do something like this : $translate.instant('ID_to_be_translated',null,null,'en-CA');

Comment: Also please note that instant was not available from the beginning. angular-translate should be above 2.13 i believe.

Comment: Thanks. that seemed to work. Not sure why I didn't think of trying nulls. 

Followup question: the first call of translate.instant uses the fallback (presumably because it doesn't yet have access to the translation files. 
The second time its run it works. Is there some way to force get the translation file right before .instant is used?

Comment: You can try to have instant inside $translateChangeSuccess event. But not sure how to force to get translational file.